# Relative url done right with ProxyHTMLURLMap?

Tags: apache, redirect, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy-html

For example psweb1.example.com:8002/main/login/login.jsp needs to redirect to psweb1.example.com/demo1/main/login/login.jsp

and psweb1.example.com:8002/content/* needs to direct to psweb1.example.com/demo1/content/*

I cannot get the proper relative paths redirected. Any help is appreciated.

This is my config in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName psweb1.example.com
        ServerAlias psweb1.example.com

        ProxyPass /demo1/ http://psweb1.example.com:8002/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap http://psweb1.example.com:8002/ /demo1
        <Location /demo1/>
                ProxyPassReverse  http://psweb1.example.com:8002/
                SetOutputFilter proxy-html
                ProxyHTMLURLMap   /           /demo1/
                ProxyHTMLURLMap   /demo1        /demo1
                RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: any comment is appreciated

Comment: can anyone help ? =)